# High CPU usage from Explorer.exe - Suspecting Dropbox and/or Onedrive shell integration at fault

Tags: windows-10, dropbox, onedrive, process-explorer, sysinternals

I'm experiencing high CPU usage from Explorer.exe and I am using SysInternals' Process Explorer to try to diagnose the issue.

Frequently I will get a CPU History graph like this (or worse, showing even more red). 
[image: Screenshot of SysInternals' Process Explorer showing CPU usage for Explorer.exe]

Here is the command-line : [image: SCreenshot of SysInternals Process Explorer showing command-line for Explorer.exe]

The 'System Idle Processes will frequently be around 0.1%. And while the computer remains 'largely' responsive, it can take between 18 seconds and 2 minutes (yes, I timed it with an iPhone) to open the context menu when right-clicking on a file in Windows File Explorer. Even if that file is not in a Dropbox or OneDrive folder.

Speaking of which I currently have Dropbox installed, and OneDrive accounts connected to my work, and personal accounts. The Work one is completely synced at present, however my personal account is trying to sync 100,000 files, which is taking weeks to do. The work one was complaining that syncing was taking a while due to high service demand, but I removed some SharePoint synced folders and now that seems to have caught up.

When I open Explorer and the scrolling green background of the address bar can sometimes take minutes - if not not completing at all, sometimes, to stop scrolling.

Here is an instance where Explorer goes High CPU usage: [image: Screenshot of SysInternals' Process Explorer showing CPU usage going high]

When this happens I can sometimes get it to stop by closing open Windows Explorer windows (which I don't want to always do because I have folders open to access files or projects that I'm working on), or by suspending OneDrive for a couple of hours - which is annoying as I really want the folders to sync.

When I suspended OneDrive (through the menu option to pause synchronisation) the high usage remained until I closed all open Explorer windows. Then this particular process disappeared. Which it doesn't always do.

I'm willing to do more digging with the SysInternals tools if anyone can guide me in the right direction, or point me to me decent tutorials.

**EDIT:** I have disabled some context menus, and I'm working through making sure context menus stay responsive. For instance all the dropbox ones are currently disabled. The other night I was sat watching Twitch and not really doing anything on the computer, and noticed the Twitch started buffering badly, and it was because the Explorer.exe process had gone very high usage again 'randomly'. How can I dig deeper into this process using ProcExp to see why it is so high at times?

**EDIT 2: ** I ran `SFC`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.
```

Comment: Set both OneDrive and Dropbox to disables on start-up and see if the issue is present after a restart. This will narrow it down. If the CPU usage looks better, enable dropbox only and see if it's causing the issue.

Comment: @NiallJones I already do this. Dropbox and OneDrive only start when I want them to. You want me to see if high CPU usage occurs without OneDrive and/or DropBox running? What are you suspecting?

Comment: You have a problematic context menu entry in one, or multiple, context menus.  Use Nirsoft's [ShellMenuView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) to narrow down which one is the offending one through a process of elimination: select half the entries and disable them > if problem remains, re-enable those and disable the other half > if problem resolves, re-enable half the ones you disabled, re-enable, and test > repeat.

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC.  First, exit Dropbox and exit OneDrive so they are not running. Then open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart when done and test Windows Explorer.

Comment: @JW0914 thanks, I'm currently disabling and working through to narrow these down.

Comment: @John What are DISM and SFC ?

Comment: DISM is Deployment Image Servicing and Management and I use its simple form (dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restoreheath) . This restores system programs and libraries from the image storage location on the computer. SFC is System File Checker (SFC /SCANNOW) and this will scan all protected system files, and replace corrupted files with a cached copy located on the computer. This is a good way to correct ordinary problems.

Comment: @John The likely issue isn't a problem with Explorer or a Windows system file, or at least I've never come across this issue where it's not being caused by a 3rd party context menu entry.  Running `DISM` then `SFC` at least once a month is good practice, but in this scenario it's not likely to correct the issue being experienced.

Comment: The idea of trying DISM was purely a suggestion to see if it might work. If not, then it may be necessary to uninstall Dropbox and Onedrive temporarily, do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link and then install Dropbox and Onedrive after the repair

Comment: @JW0914 I am still experimenting with context menu entries , not restricting it to onedrive and Dropbox , but what would cause the sudden spike in CPU usage in that Explorer instance while not actively manipulating files?

Comment: @cometbill The fastest way to determine which is the entry causing the issue is to disable half (described above) and continue on from there, enabling/disabling 50% at a time until you've narrowed down the offending entry.  As to your question, I can't provide a technical answer, but your issue is almost certainly being caused by a 3rd party context meny entry (there's multiple contenxt meny categories you'll need to check, such as drive, directory, directory background, etc.).  This process takes all of 10min at most from start to finish.